# Is true a Timer inside div not running when the Div Hidden?

Tags: asp.net, timer, asp.net-ajax

I have 2 timers on the ASP.NET.

I put on the div one of timer that the div visiblity is false, say `TIMER1`. and second I put second timer (say `Timer2`) in the another div where that div is visibility is true.

But if I set it to visibility true for all div. The timers Work normaly together.

The questions, why if the div is hide (from code behind) the timer is not running? otherwise both of timers is running normally if div is set on visibility true.
Is true a Timer inside div not running when the Div Hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `Visibility` to `false` in code behind, ASP does not render the `div` on the page at all. What you can do is, set the CSS `visibility` property to `hidden`. This way it will rendered on the page but not visible and the timer inside it will work.

```
<div style="visibility: hidden">......</div>
```

Comment: It's worked!. The problem is Div cannot shown during The timer. You right, ASP not render if using runat=server and set to visible=false/true. But it will rendering with runat=server and CSS under code behind.
Thank you @Racil Hilan